Depicting different shapes of the same real world entity in an ER Diagram
Given an entity A represented by tableA, that I am going to perform certain transformations on (e.g. pivot, standardise) and store/materialise in a second table tableB should I depict an entity B for tableB too in an ER Diagram? ..after all it is the same logical entity.

According to Peter Chen who is at the origin of ERD modeling:

An entity is a "thing" which can be distinctly identified.

This definition does not impose any implementation constraint nor imply an equivalence between a table and an entity, even if there is a high correlation between the two concepts:

You could therefore show in an ERD a single entity, that is in practice implemented with two tables using the same primary key to ensure the consistent identity of the "thing".

However, if table A and table B have different primary keys, there would objectively be two distinctly identifiable things, hence a separate entity should be used.


